# Is there a ready made gruntfile available for Drupal Bootstrap Child Theme (SASS)

Tags: 7, theming

**This applies to Drupal 7.**

I am fairly new to grunt and can't really make much sense of out of a gruntfile. I've just started with a drupal child theme (which has been created off bootstrap SASS startkit).

Can you point out a readymade grunt file which I can use to watch and compile my scss (output as css) and minify js.

Answer (score 1):

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
grunt.initConfig({
compass: {
 dist: {
    options: {
      sassDir: 'sass',
      cssDir: 'css',
      environment: 'production',
    },
  },
},
watch: {
  css: {
    files: ['sass/*.scss'],
    tasks: ['compass'],
  },
},
});
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');
grunt.registerTask('default', ['compass']);
};
```

Comment: Just saw it here. You might like this package for the JS part, https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-uglify

Comment: Absolutely, the js part is also very nicely explained in the official doc, but this one is also equally helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a Drupal subtheme, but an alternative is looking into the Drupal Bootstrap theme and checking out the grunt configuration they have.

- https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap
- http://cgit.drupalcode.org/bootstrap/tree/?h=7.x-3.x

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out ( I wasn't aware it existed!) but it seems like an overkill. I've figured out how to use a custom grunt file which works irrespective of drupal or non-drupal site. And the official documentation -http://gruntjs.com/sample-gruntfile was massively helpful in this case. Happy to post back my discovery.

Comment: That's great! An answer with your file would be a nice addition

Comment: I've posted my answer above.